# invalid_grant error with Google Cloud Storage and Service Account

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage

I'm getting an invalid_grant error when I try to access Google Cloud Storage API with Service Accounts. I can't figure out what's wrong with the following code. Any idea ? It's my first application using Google Storage API. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Source Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);

    Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId("XXXX")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();

    Storage storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
            credential).setApplicationName("test")
            .build();

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Bucket> buckets = storage.buckets().list("XXXX").execute().getItems();
    if(buckets != null) {
        for(Bucket b : buckets) {
            list.add(b.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

**Error and stack trace**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}

at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:269)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:858)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at GoogleStorageFetcher.main(GoogleStorageFetcher.java:143)
```

Comment: Hrm...I don't see anything wrong. Your service account looks like a long email address ending in "@developer.gserviceaccount.com", right? And "key.p12" is in the right place to be opened like that? Might be worth trying the command line sample app to make sure your credentials are valid: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/plus-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample/?repo=samples&r=1dd135aa1dfa0b5d326ba2a0c795ed18cd052495

Comment: Thanks. I was actually using the Client ID (ending in .apps.googleusercontent.com) instead of the email address (ending in @developer.gserviceaccount.com).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This error was due to an incorrect Service Account ID. I was using the Client ID (ending in .apps.googleusercontent.com) instead of the email address (ending in @developer.gserviceaccount.com). There is no problem with the email address.

Comment: I made the same mistake. Thx for sharing!

Comment: Do you know if @iam.gserviceaccount.com is valid email address as well? When I create a service account, it always gives me an email address with the format.

Answer (score 12):

I know this question is from a year ago.

I had this error: **Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""**

In my case, the problem was solved synchronizing the server clock with NTP. The firewall of my server was blocking a port and the server's time was not updated correctly.

For more information, visit the ["Invalid Grant"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/authorization#invalid_grant) section on the "Management API - Authorization" help page (relative to Google Analytics, but relevant for the error)

Comment: had the same problem when my computer's time was out of sync with reality.  the google auth gave this error.

Comment: How did you guys fix the sync?? My machine already had ubuntu's time zone on its /etc/ntp.conf.  so it means my problem is not related to this probably?

Comment: Google offers a NTP server for free: https://developers.google.com/time